# Working with querypath and nodes

Tags: 7, nodes

Im trying to use querypath module with my node and not having much luck. I have this code and I tried applying it to my node.tpl file but it only crashes the site.

Am I using this incorrectly?

```
global $base_root;
$path_url = $base_root . request_uri();
$qp = qp($path_url); 

$qp2 = $qp->find('body'); // Find the body tag.

// Now the surprising part:
if ($qp === $qp2) {
  // This will always get printed.
  print "MATCH";
}else{
    print "...";
}
```

If this is incorrect can someone please provide a working example?

Thanks

Comment: That kind of code should go in a module, not the theme. Did you really put that code in node.tpl.php ? Then the site crash is normal, as this file is used on everypage, so you're on for an infinite loop. I have trouble understanding what you're trying to achieve, so it's difficult to help.

Comment: well pretty much im just trying to do a if else statement, $qp = url of current page, $qp2 = look for the body div and the if statement is if its there print match if not print ... the reason i say it is not working correctly because i cant change body into any div or a non existing one and it will always output match as if it is there when i know it isnt.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with querypath to help you on this, and it's not really a Drupal question if you ask me. Maybe `qp()` function and the `->find` method both return true ?